# Triple integrals. Forced to use cylindrical coordinates :(

Tags: integration

Volume of the solid bounded above by the plane $z=y$ and bellow by the paraboloid $z=x^2+y^2$.

I'm am confident on the bounds $r^2 \leq z \leq r\sin(\theta)$ deriving from $x^2 + y^2$ (the paraboloid) and $y$ (the plane)

and $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$ from knowing it is only all positive $y$ and all positive $z$

I am not sure about the bounds for $r$. My approach is to maybe set the plane equal to the paraboloid so I can find the intersection and the shadow region.
I think I would get something like $x^2 + (y^2 - y + 1) =1$
So I guess the radius for that would be 1. so $0 \leq r \leq 1$ ?
But I'm not even positive that that is a circle.

Help on checking my bounds? I'm not positive that any of them are correct.

Comment: $y=x^2+y^2$ _does_ give that formula; from there, though, I would convert to cylindrical coordinates. You get $r\sin(\theta)=r^2.$ Solve for $r$.

Answer (score 1):

When you put the $z=y$ into your paraboloid equation, you got an implicit equation of a circle, but the circle is offset from the centre now. Just put the equation in the right form:

$$x^2+(y-\tfrac12)^2=\tfrac14$$

The domain of integration is therefore a circle of radius $1/2$ with the center at $(0,1/2)$. You can integrate over this domain... or if you really want cylindrical coordinates about the $(0,0)$ point, write the paraboloid as $z=r^2$ and, combining with the plane, you get $r^2=r\sin\theta$, which you already got by yourself. So the bound is simply $0<r<\sin\theta$. Of course, looking at the domain we got earlier, you can see you must only consider $0<\theta<\pi$, otherwise you repeat the integration domain twice (and violate $0<r$).